# Ember.js: Proper way to iterate through object in model?

Tags: javascript, object, model-view-controller, model, ember.js

I'm developing my first EmberJS app after following some tutorials as practice. It simply contains a list of 'tables', 'columns', and 'rows' similar to a database.

Link to the problematic page: http://www.kangarooelectronics.com/fakeDB/#/tables/edit/2

My issue is that when I go to remove a column I get:
**Object # has no method 'deleteRecord'**
As I understand this is due to the object I'm iterating through having no references to the controller because of the way I am constructing the array that I use to create my list.

Removing tables works fine, which are listed in the following fashion:

```
{{#each model itemController='TableList'}}
    <a {{action removeTable this}}>Delete</a>
{{/each}}
```

I'm iterating through the columns via:

```
{{#each column in currentColumns itemController='TablesEdit'}}
    <a {{action removeColumn column}}>Drop</a>
{{/each}}
```

Snippet from FIXTURES object:

```
FakeDB.Table.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Users',
        columns: {
            1:{'colId':1, 'name':'name'},
            2:{'colId':2, 'name':'favorite color'},
            3:{'colId':3, 'name':'phone number'}
        },
// ...snip... //
```

I am getting 'currentColumns' via:

```
FakeDB.Table = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    columns: DS.attr('object'),
    rows: DS.attr('object'),
    currentColumns: function() {
        var newColumns = $.map(this.get('columns'), function(k, v) {
            return [k];
        });
        return newColumns;
    }.property('columns'),
// ..snip.. //
```

Here you can see my problem... it's obvious that my 'column' isn't going to have any methods from my controller. I tried something like this:

```
FakeDB.Adapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

FakeDB.Adapter.map('FakeDB.Table', {
    columns: {embedded: 'load'},
    rows: {embedded: 'load'}
});

FakeDB.Columns = DS.Model.extend({
    colId: DS.attr('integer'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

FakeDB.Rows = DS.Model.extend({
    colId: DS.attr('integer'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

But I couldn't get {{#each column in columns}} to work with that.

Any suggestions? I'm going to read the docs again and will post back if I find a solution.
Thanks!

EDIT:
So I think I found another solution, but I'm still running into a little issue.

```
FakeDB.Table = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    columns: FakeDB.Columns.find().filter(function(item, index, self) {
        if(item.tableID == 1) { return true; }
    })
});
```

Still not sure what to replace 'item.tableID == 1' with so that I get items with the tableID referencing to the current page...

Columns are structured as...

```
FakeDB.Columns.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        tableID: 1,
        name: 'name'
    },
// ...snip... //
```

But now I get:
**assertion failed: Your application does not have a 'Store' property defined. Attempts to call 'find' on model classes will fail. Please provide one as with 'YourAppName.Store = DS.Store.extend()'**

I am in fact defining a 'Store' property...

Comment: Update:
Almost there, removed the columns reference from FakeDB.Table.
Created a FakeDB.TablesEditRoute, can read params.table_id. Just have to filter the columns and then it will work (can list all ATM).

Then I have to work on the relationships aspect and making it more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm developing my first EmberJS app after following some tutorials as practice. It simply contains a list of 'tables', 'columns', and 'rows' similar to a database.

Most databases do contain a list of tables, rows and columns. Most web applications contain a fixed set of tables with pre-defined columns and a dynamic list of rows. If this is your first ember app i would recommend starting with something that keeps you on the happy path.

> I am in fact defining a 'Store' property...

True but ember is complaining because store is not available before ember app is initialized. Anything that accesses the store should be in a framework hook of some kind. It can't be used when defining your objects, which wouldn't make a lot of sense anyway.

Probably what you meant to do was make a computed property called `columns` like this:

```
FakeDB.Table = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  columns: function() { 
    FakeDB.Columns.find().filter(function(item, index, self) {
      if(item.tableID == 1) { return true; }
    })
  }.property('')
});
```